# How to change customer group based on specific product that has been bought

Tags: magento-2.1, orders, event-observer, customer-group

This question has been asked before but I'm trying to do this with Magento 2.1.

Would the correct approach be to create an observer for the "sales_model_service_quote_submit_success" event? and then look up the ordered Item's SKU's/IDs and if one matches my special product then lookup and update the customer group?

And would this approach also work with orders created in the backend by an admin?

Here's a snippet from my observer code (be gentle, this is the first PHP I've ever written let alone the first Magento 2.1 module)

```
/**
     * @param Observer $observer
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute( Observer $observer ) {


        $ThisDoesntEXIST->orthis();


        die("test");

        if ( $this->isCustomerLoggedIn() ) {

            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

            $ledenProduct = $this->scopeConfiguration->getValue('marviq_checkout_config/product/product', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
            $groupId = $this->scopeConfiguration->getValue('marviq_checkout_config/product/customer_group', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

            $customerId    = $order->getCustomerId();
            $customer      = $this->customerRepository->getById( $customerId );

            $items = $order->getAllItems();
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $itemId = $item->getItemId();
                if ($itemId == "Special") {
                    $customer->setGroupId($groupId);
                    $customer->save();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if customer is logged in
     *
     * @return bool
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    private function isCustomerLoggedIn() {
        return (bool) $this->httpContext->getValue( CustomerContext::CONTEXT_AUTH );
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to change this after place order?

Comment: Correct, after an order has been successfully made, i.e. after they have paid at the payment-service-provider and have come back to my Magento application.